# numpy python class calling wrong __setitem__

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following class:

```
class autoArray2(numpy.ndarray):
    def __new__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = numpy.array(*args, **kwargs)
        return(obj)

    def __setitem__(self, coords, value):
        print("HERE")
```

However it seems the `array.__setitem__` is being called instead of the one I've specified.

```
a = numpy.array([[1,2],[2,3]])
b = autoArray2(a)
a[0,0] = 1
```

"HERE" is not printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subclassing a numpy array is a little bit tricky. 
[Stefan van der Walt's slides](http://mentat.za.net/numpy/numpy_advanced_slides/) and the [numpy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html)
are good places to begin if you want to subclass.

```
import numpy as np

class AutoArray2(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array):
        # Input array is an already formed ndarray instance
        # We first cast to be our class type
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        return obj
    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return
    def __setitem__(self, coords, value):
        print("HERE")

a = np.array([[1,2],[2,3]])
b = AutoArray2(a)
b[0,0] = 1
```

yields

```
HERE
```

The key ingredient is the call to `view(cls)`. Without it, you are returning a plain `ndarray`, not an AutoArray2 instance.

Also, `a[0,0] = 1` is using `a` -- the plain `ndarray`. To use `b`'s `__setitem__` you need `b[0,0] = 1`.

Comment: Thanks. I saw this and tried it but then couldn't get the array memory copied properly and so tried another method. I guess this is the correct way of doing this.

Comment: Also, good catch on the a[0,0] = 1 ... I think that was just me typing in the command instead of copy paste. I just checked and the original class indeed did not print the "HERE".

Comment: @unutbu Why calling `b[:]` does not call `AutoArray2.__setitem__`?

Comment: @Hernan: Do you mean when there is an assignment like `b[:] = 0`? In Python2/NumPy, `b[:] = 0` causes [`__setslice__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.setslice) to be called, not `__setitem__`.

Comment: @unutbu I though that __setslice__ was deprecated in old NumPy Versions. thanks a lot!